# How to set textView unclickable

Tags: android, kotlin, textview

I have a clickable text, when clicked an HTTP request is made. I want to disable the text when it is clicked until the request response arrives but there doesn't seem to be a method to set the textview's clickable attribute to false. Is there a way to this?

Edit: Okay I've found it. Apparently I can directly modify isClickable attribute of the TextView. This does the trick:

```kotlin
textView.isClickable = false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the TextView programmatically, use

```
textView.clickable = false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `enabled` property of a `View`, like this:

`android:enabled="false"`